# Javscript / Ajax Account created by bots

Tags: javascript, php, bots, account, matomo

I have done a simply Javascript change ID to avoid account created by bots:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#FormAccountCreateTmp").attr("id", "FormAccountCreate");
}, 5400);
```

So after 5.4 seconds, the form with Id `FormAccountCreateTmp` has the Id `FormAccountCreate` and then the jQuery / Javascript can be executed:

```
$("body").validator().on("submit", "#FormAccountCreate", function(e) {
    if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        buttonLoading($("#BtAccountCreate"));
        var values = $("form#FormAccountCreate").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://mywebsite.com/sig" + "nup/aja" + "x/ajax" + "_account" + "_create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: values,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#AjaxSignup").empty().html(data);
            },
            error: function(exception) { console.log(exception); }
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But since few days I have bots reaching the page signup (first page visited of the website) and validating the form **23 seconds** later!

```
185.72.244.24 - - [08/Feb/2020:02:31:25 +0000] "GET /en/signup/ HTTP/2.0" 200 21891 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
...
185.72.244.24 - - [08/Feb/2020:02:31:48 +0000] "POST /signup/ajax/ajax_account_create.php HTTP/2.0" 200 584 "https://mywebsite.com/en/signup/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"
```

What could I do to block these bots without adding a captcha. I can see these bots IPS are not referenced in my [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) visitors logs. So there might be a PHP or Javascript way to block them.

Why do some people create these bots to create random account? There is nothing to earn by creating these accounts, I don't understand their goals.

Comment: I understand using a visible recaptcha can be annoying for some users, but what about Google invisible recaptcha ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet so I'll post a more elaborate response here

Also check out https://elasticemail.com/blog/marketing_tips/how-to-prevent-bots-from-spamming-your-sign-up-forms, it was my source and has a few other options on it. It talks about **blog signup forms** but it is still relatable.

### "Confirm you email" email

A lot of websites use this to not only validate that the email linked to your account is yours, but to also confirm that the user isn't a bot.

This would force whoever was controlling the bots to manually validate every account.

Of course you wouldn't want account records listed in your database or wherever you store them forever, so simply add a record of when the account was created on account creation. Then create a cron job that runs once a day and scans for accounts that are x days old and haven't validate their email. At that point you would delete the account and optionally create a record linked to the accounts email or IP address that they previously failed to validate their email address and could be a bot.

Though this option would deal with bots you have to also think of the cons

- You have to have a cron job running
- Bots will still be able to sign up(They won't get access to your website though)
- Depending on how long you let users wait to validate their email the longer a bot account could be active.

The choice is up to you. I'm sorry that I can't give you an immediate solution to prevent bots at the actual signup process, but bots are improving constantly and sooner or later bots may find a way around captcha.